# Asp.net force set the user client variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement for my website to automatically set the user agent to IE9.

Like so

[image]

While the Document mode can be set in the aspx page with:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5" />
```

I have tried to set the user client from here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

But it still does not work.

Anyone have an idea what else needs to be added?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do so is through the meta tag, as you mentioned, so you would want a meta tag like this

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: That works. But that's not what I want. I want to change the user agent string.

Comment: Uh... The user agent string is what the *client* tells the server he is. The server doesn't get to decide that...

Comment: I guess what I am saying, is how can I trick the web server into thinking that my IE11 browser is actually IE9?

Comment: You can override it in the developer tools on IE on your client. But you cannot set the client to use a certain user agent on the server. That's something only the client gets to decide.